# Are code coverage questions on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question comes from reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563446/qa-code-coverage-metrics-collection) (I have not voted yet). Note that I am maintaining a distinction between "code review" and "code coverage" here; the latter in my experience is not related to reviewing code *quality* but rather tracking the portions of code that are hit (or not) during execution.

---

"Code coverage" tooling is commonly used by programmers and others in the Software Development Lifecycle. I would say it may fall under the "tools commonly used by programmers" portion of what is on topic here, but can't help but think there may be a better place on SE for this sort of question. For example we have:

- [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

In this case, the asker is asking about code coverage on the whole for a given software application, not just at their project level. I'm not sure whether this is considered on topic for Stack Overflow or if it belongs instead on one of the other sites, particularly the other sites I mentioned above.

My gut says it probably belongs on SQA as this is not *quite* programming related but instead related to the process of code coverage itself. It feels too broad in scope for programming Q&A. But I first wanted to garner some feedback before casting a close vote on a question that is potentially on topic and could be improved in other ways instead of closure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gathering code coverage *programmatically* is, indeed, on-topic on Stack Overflow. After all, code coverage tools are tools commonly used by programmers in programming context (and not on a boat).

That said, this *specific* question is *not* on-topic on Stack Overflow. It *could* be given the abovementioned, but as specified, it both lacks detail (the technology stack) and is too broad (gathering code coverage for a single project is complex enough task to warrant a book, let alone doing so *across* multiple projects).

As an aside regarding being on-topic on SQAT: being on-topic on another site on the network does not automatically make a question off-topic here. However, the caveat hardly applies in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't meant to imply questions can't be on topic for multiple sites in the network; those were just the two I was considering leaving a comment directing to after a close vote.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest ah, I did not mean you implied it either - just a note for other readers (as the misunderstanding that being on-topic on another site automatically makes it off-topic here is quite common).

Comment: That question is on topic but too broad. The entire question is about programming but includes elements that can't be reasonably answered on any SE site, since it breaks the Q&A model.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with that question isn't topicness, it's too broad. The help center includes a page for questions [that even if on topic, aren't good fit for the Q&A format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). That question specifically asks for two things: "pointers or links to useful blogs would be appreciated if available", which are known to cause problems. The other thing that it asks is "Am I way off base?" with respect of whenever there's a difference between application or project. That later can be reasonably answered on any site and it's about programming. If someone is inclined to re-scope the question into asking that instead, the question can be answered.

To answer the question in the title: yes, questions about code coverage are on topic, so long as they are clear, reasonably scoped and not trying to gather opinions.